# What does the `workspaces not supported` message mean when running `terraform workspace list`?

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws, terraform-provider-azure

I have main.tf:

```
terraform {
  backend "remote" {
    organization = "myorg"

    workspaces {
      name = "some-workspace-like-so"
    }
  }
}
```

Ran `terraform init` successfully. However if I then run `terraform workspace list` to see other workspaces in my organization I get the error `workspaces not supported`. Is this an org setting, a configuration issue, me misunderstanding how the command is supposed to work, something else?

Comment: can you check the TF_WORKSPACE environment variable ?

Comment: unset TF_WORKSPACE you can give it a try and let me know

Comment: `echo $TF_WORKSPACE` returns null. Ran `unset $TF_WORKSPACE` anyway and `terraform workspace list` and same result.

Comment: something is going on with that null you get first

Comment: Try to use prefix ="Your app" instead of name = "some-workspace-like-so" and let me know

Answer (score 3):

Try using the workspaces block's prefix parameter rather than its name argument to handle the several TFC workplaces.

```java
terraform {
  backend "remote" {
    hostname = "app.terraform.io"
    organization = "org"

    workspaces {
      prefix = "my-infra"
    }
  }
}
```

***Reference:*** https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/22802 *by saitotqr*